Modify face orientations in bulk
I wrote a script for batch change orientation. Here is a script I wrote:
import bpy

selected_object = bpy.context.object

if selected_object and selected_object.type == 'MESH':
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = selected_object
    selected_object.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    mesh = bpy.context.edit_object.data

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

    bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

else:
    print("The currently selected object is not a Mesh object")

This works, but there is a problem, which is that after I run it, there is a certain face of some object or more than two or even more, how do I tell if this face is red or blue, add the condition


Hello and welcome to BSE. When you say "in bulk" how do you do this? You can simply select all your objects and execute this script and it should work. If it doesn't work then your object is probably not manifold. Can you share the problematic object? https://blend-exchange.com

Sure, here's the link to that file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/xq95QZ2R/, this file is relatively simple, I also put the script in the file, after I run the script, I need this object is to need the X axis or - X axis is the same color, this is just an example, not a batch of objects

I checked the object but it is not manifold. No thickness so it's not possible to know which direction is your "correct" side.

What I need is that the two faces are in the same direction at the same time, now they are in two different directions, and the reason for these two is that there is no thickness so that the faces of these two faces are not facing in the same direction, right?

I noticed that if you switch the 2 meshes direction around on the X-axis, normals_make_consistent will always make the convex "outer" part of each mesh as blue/surface. So the only way you can make all faces regardless if convex or concave consistently face the same direction is to pick a direction of your choice you want the face normals to point into and then do the checks and flips for each face.

So for example if you want every face to to have its Face Normal point toward the +X axis then you have to iterate through every face and check if the face's Face Normal's x-component is positive value and if it's not then flip the face with bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals(). But then for closed manifold meshes like the cube this will not work because then everything faces in one direction and you will require to run normals_make_consistent. And there is no real way to tell when to use which method. So you have to specify every object in your post so we can find a specific solution.

Ok, I'll try it out. Thank you
